# How to solve TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

This is the `layer.py` code:

```py
def repeat_vector(inputs):

    layer_for_repeat, layer_for_getting_rep_num = inputs
    n=K.shape(layer_for_getting_rep_num)[1]
    name='custom_repeat_vector'
    repeated_vector = RepeatVector(n,name)(layer_for_repeat)
    # shape == (batch_size, seq_len, vector_dim)
    return repeated_vector
```

And this is `lambda_layer.py` code:

```py
class Lambda(Layers)

  @tf.__internal__.tracking.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

    def __init__(self, function, output_shape=None, mask=None, arguments=None, **kwargs ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.arguments = arguments or {}
        self.function = function

        if mask is not None:
            self.supports_masking = True
        self.mask = mask
        self._output_shape = output_shape

        # Warning on every invocation will be quite irksome in Eager mode.
        self._already_warned = False

        function_args = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(function).args
        self._fn_expects_training_arg = "training" in function_args
        self._fn_expects_mask_arg = "mask" in function_args
```

I have been trying to solve this problem. but nothing seems to be working:

```
errors are:
 File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/tools/fetch.py", line 40, in <module>
get_trained_model(fetch_from_s3=True)
  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cachetools/__init__.py", line 737, in wrapper
    v = func(*args, **kwargs)
  
File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/cakechat/dialog_model/factory.py", line 76, in get_trained_model
    model.init_model()
 
 File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/cakechat/dialog_model/keras_model.py", line 30, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  
File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/cakechat/dialog_model/keras_model.py", line 277, in init_model
    self._model = self._build_model()
  
File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/cakechat/dialog_model/model.py", line 253, in _build_model
    decoder_training_model, decoder_model = self._decoder(y_tokens_emb_model, condition_emb_model)
  
File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/cakechat/dialog_model/model.py", line 387, in _decoder
    repeated_conditioned_tv = Lambda(function=repeat_vector,mask=lambda inputs, inputs_masks: inputs_masks[0],  
 
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 838, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/lambda_layer.py", line 209, in call
    result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
 
File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/cakechat-master/cakechat/dialog_model/layers.py", line 20, in repeat_vector
    repeated_vector = RepeatVector(n,name)(layer_for_repeat)

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: did you put `self` as an argument in __init__()? Could you please put your class's code on the question?

Comment: @chronosirius Yes i did pass self in __init__() but it's still not working . I have put my class code on question.

Comment: How are you instantiating the class?